# MS access2013 datasheet shows display values, but listbox only shows ID

Tags: ms-access, listbox

I have a table named "customers", and a table named "cases". These relate to real estate transactions. On the table "cases" I have a field for "other party", which lets you enter a new customer or pick from an existing one if we have already had that person in our database from a different transaction.

I have created a form with a listbox so I can search all the case records via the customer and other party fields (I also show some other info about the case but am not needing to search that info). In formview the listbox shows the customer name, but only shows the ID number for the other party. When I go to the rowsource, buildevent, and see the query in datasheet view, the records display the way I want them to -by name, not showing ID numbers.

Why won't it display correctly on the listbox??? Please help! I have spent way to many hours trying to figure this out :( This is my first time using access and I am just figuring it out as I go.

this is the SQL from the query in the listbox rowsource:

```
SELECT Query3.Customers.ID, Query3.[Last Name], Query3.[First Name],  Query3.[Other Party], Query3.[Property Address], Query3.[Assigned To], Query3.Lawyer FROM Query3;
```

and this is the SQL from Query3:

```
PARAMETERS [ [forms]]![FRM_SearchMulti]![SrchText] Text ( 255 );
SELECT CasesALL.*
FROM CasesALL
WHERE (((CasesALL.[Last Name]) Like "*" & [forms]![FRM_SearchMulti]![SrchText] & "*")) OR (((CasesALL.[First Name]) Like "*" & [forms]![FRM_SearchMulti]![SrchText] & "*")) OR (((CasesALL.[Other Party]) Like "*" & [forms]![FRM_SearchMulti]![SrchText] & "*"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Listboxes and combo boxes have a hidden column feature, usually a primary/foreign key of underlying table. Users generally do not know which primary key they should pick, hence the connecting name/item displays for their selection. Your situation sounds like the key is not being hidden but displaying and with two columns designated, you do not see the `Other Party` field.

To fix, under Property Sheet / Format Tab of the listbox, adjust Column Count and corresponding Column Widths according to your query (i.e., recordsource of listbox). As shown below the first column of query is hidden with 0 inches of display while the next two fields will display at 2 inches:

```
Column Count: 3
Column Widths: 0"; 2"; 2"  
...
List Width: 4"
```

Be sure column widths add up to your List Width or there will be cut-offs. Also, inches are automatically added when you enter numbers. Finally, do note the data value of the listbox will be whatever is designated in Bound Column under Property Sheet / Data tab:

```
Bound Column: 1
```

Usually, the bound column is the hidden field or it wouldn't be hidden or used!

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but I had already done that party correctly (I am pretty sure)

Comment: This is what the form/listbox looks like. I had already specified 7 columns and the first one to 0" so it doesn't show. You can see from the image that this problem also arises on the "assigned to" column.

![image of listbox ]https://www.dropbox.com/s/y6safaieakw0www/Untitled.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Go to the table design of your CasesALL table and place cursor first on the [Other Party] and then on [Assigned To] fields. At the bottom under Field Properties, there is a LookUp tab. Check to see if `Display Control` is set to `Listbox` with specifications like the form. Try changing it to the default `Textbox`.

Comment: that didn't help :( is there any piece of code I can write into the query to take the id value that is showing up and replace it with the display value?

Comment: You have to create separate lookup tables for [Other Party] and [Assigned To] values to correspond to lookups and call those values in Query3.

Comment: Attach a dropbox link of database, or screenshots of Query3 datasheet view, CasesAll datasheet view, and CasesAll design view (list of fields and data types).

Comment: ok...here is the DB:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rjwy39keu4t6n4l/TESTdatabase.accdb?dl=0
if you look at the form that opens up (FRM_SearchMulti3) and view the querybuilder datasheet for the listbox (SearchResults) you see that everything displays correctly, but when you look at the form itself in displayview, no luck. What I would like to achieve is this:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3cJinHSSkuI
.... but I can't seem to make it happen.

Comment: Just took a look at the db and the issue is exactly what I mentioned above. In the querybuilder datasheet, both [Other Party] and [Assigned To] are combo boxes and from their table origins they have List Boxes as their LookUp display control. Revert display control back to textboxes and in the Query4 (CasesAll) inner join their underlying tables ([Customers Extended] and [Employees Extended]) and select the names and not the codes (i.e. [Other Party] name, not [Other Party] ID).

Comment: ....I had to do some tinkering to get it working, but yay! it is now...thank you for all your help!

Comment: - Here's hoping you can help with another small problem! : )
I have split the database and distributed it - it works great!...but now I need to make a small change to the front end, however, when I make **any** changes at all (even just changing some label text from BOLD to Underlined, it becomes very slow. Any ideas on what would cause this?

Comment: It has nothing to do with design changes but how you are running the front end. Don't use internet folders (Dropbox, Google Drive, SkyDrive, etc.) and don't use flash keys -only network or CPU machine drives. Finally, it may be your machine, so check RAM capacity (close other apps) and disk space.

Comment: Front end is running locally on a PC, backend is on our company server no internet or flash drives. I noticed that if I made changes and closed (which seemed to save the changes anyway) there was no problem, but as soon as I hit the save button everything slows to a crawl. File size is 20mb which seems crazy and then I also did a "save as" to save it with another file name for testing. That new file seemed to work at the correct speed and also reduced file size to 4mb - what on earth was removed to reduce the size by that much? and can I trust it? much better size for distributing.

Comment: That is a sure symptom to [Compact & Repair](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Compact-and-repair-a-database-6ee60f16-aed0-40ac-bf22-85fa9f4005b2) your original database (under External Tab on Ribbon). Temporary objects, cache, system variables, etc. can cause bloating over time, impacting performance.

Comment: hello again....here's hoping you are still out there : ) Back to the last problem, where I need to make some cosmetic changes to my front end. Every time I do anything, my listbox (that has a text search) slows down to a crawl. I can have another instance of the front end open that hasn't had changes and it works fine, but in the copy I am editing,the minute I decide to change anything (bold a word, change the spelling of button text etc) it's like mud. I have compacted and repaired several times, no luck this time.

Comment: Might be a corrupt form. Try creating a new database and import all objects, then re-link backend tables. And consider same with new form, recreating controls. Be sure every user uses their own FrontEnd on personal machines but all connect to same BackEnd. Could also be a hardware or network issue. See if other files, docs, apps run slow. If so, clean/defragment/tune-up your PC.

Answer (score 0):

You probably miss to set columnwidth(s) of the listbox to: 0